# Inconsistent SVG rect width

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg chart which I generate with Javascript. The preblem is that my rects are not consistent - some of them are wider than other although all have same width - 7.16 ....

[image]

Part of the code

```
var svg1 = document.querySelector('.rects'); //group tag
for(var i = 0; i<256; i++){
  var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");

  rect.classList.add("rect");
  rect.setAttribute("x", counter);
  rect.setAttribute("y", "396"- +json[i*3].close/1.5);
  rect.setAttribute("height", +json[i*3].close/1.5); //width is set in CSS


  svg1.appendChild(rect);
  counter = counter+8.88;

}
```

It is all in this Svg tag

```
<svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="small" viewBox="0 0 1200 460" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
    <use xlinkHref="#viewBoxBorder"/>
```

Comment: a live example of this would be helpful.

Comment: click on any bar
https://occupations-f8a85.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the edges of the rectangles landing halfway between two pixels. Try changing the space between your `x` coordinate from `8.88` to an integer like `8` or `10` and do the same with the width of the bars.

While vectors are infinitely scalable, it's always wise to snap hard edges to pixel values at the initial scale. This will prevent blurriness when anti-aliasing and make scaling up and down by various ratios maintain evenness.

Comment: Hi @Soviut, tnx for an answer. Unfortunately, I did not have any success, it is even worse. Changed 8.88 to 10 and 8 but nothing. Width is rounded also. I think the problem is with viewBox.

Comment: When you inspect one of the rectangles in your browser, are the x coordinates now whole numbers?

Comment: It seems that width of svg tag was causing problem. It was set to 100%. I changed it to 600px and all is good now. However if i set width to 800px it is still the same. tnx

Comment: It is not enough for your SVG coordinates to be whole numbers. They have to be pixel aligned _after scaling_ as well, otherwise they may still end up halfway between pixel boundaries.

Comment: Can you be more specific? By after scaling you mean changing viewBox? I have problem with that.. Don't know how to solve it except not to use it at all.